# IIS Webservice, weird 404 http response code

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, biztalk

I am struggling with IIS and SOAP Webservices and need a hint.

I use the BizTalk Orchestration to create a simple Webservice which calls a sql stored procedure (deploy against BizTalk and publish as WCF Service).
I happen to make it work on my development machine, but as I transport the Service to the test-environment it does not work as expected.

At first the Webservice itself is published and I can subscribe to it by downloading the WSDL file and add it to SoapUI.

But once I try to call a request, the Webserver returns a HTTP 404 as response. If I stop the BizTalk Orchestration I get an HTTP 500.
So I guess the BizTalk to IIS connection works.
But there won't be any message deployed to the MessageBox (In BizTalk I filtered Messages on the Port Name)

There are about 30 other WebServices deployed and they all use the same Web.config. They are linked to the same AppPool in IIS.

Things I tried:

- Created single IIS AppPool for the application
- Checked for correct permissions on Directory and BizTalk- / IIS-Users
- Redeployed solution and republished it as Service

Yeah, it is a shitty statement, but it works on my development machine. Which is configured the same as the target plattform, except the target is a cluster system. But I dont think thats the problem.

The Log from IIS simply shows the requests, but no Information about it.
I really have no clue where to look. Does anybody have an Idea?

EDIT I:

SOAP Response

```
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Server Error</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
               <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
               <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Your title talks about maxDate/minDate but your question is about WS connectivity. Which is it?

Comment: You are right, it saved the old draft and I did not updated it. :-S

Comment: There are a bazillion things which can cause the "it works on my machine" problem with BTS. A 404 just means that the service has not been published correctly. Does the deployment mechanism have sufficient rights to create virtual directories etc in IIS?

Comment: I think so, after seeing the published data is the same as in my working dev environment. I also confirmed that the directorys have the same privileges as the other, running webservices on my testing environment.

Comment: How are you deploying? Is it the same way the other 30 services were deployed?

Comment: Yes, I use the WCF Publishing Service Wizard within Visual Studio 2013R2. With this you can select the DLL of your BizTalk Project, then your webservice definition is beeing created. Commonly this is done once on the dev machine and then the output is copied to the testing environment, because the output of the WCF Publishing Wizard is solely based on the BizTalk Project DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

There is a internal loadbalancing before our Test- and Prod-Environment which automatically switches communication from http to https.

The WCF-CustomIsolated Receivelocation for the WebService in BizTalk had the basicHttpBinding option for the BasicHttpSecurityElement as none. Which led to the Http 404 not found error. After setting it to "transport" it was able to deal with the https rewrite in the loadbalancer and it worked.

404 Not found = Transport security failed.

Comment: Please mark this as your solution when you are able.